# How do computers understand the functionality of "random"?

Tags: logic, computer-science

This question isn't specific to any computing language and i'm not sure if it belongs here or not. It's kind of hard to explain what I mean but let me try. So for example when you tell the computer do this or do that, you are telling the computer what to do, what to compute etc... From my understanding, computers have no intelligence, they are info and an order of operation and they do what is asked from them. My question is, how would a computer know to choose a number when you ask it to choose a random number from 1 to 10 etc...?
I hope you understand my question. Cheers !

Answer (score 1):

You need to read about linear congruent generators.  Donald Knuth did a lot of fundamental work that's published in his seminal The Art of Computer Programming.

Answer (score 1):

A computer cannot generate any "random" number.  It can use an algorithm or a time stamp to come up with a seemingly random number, but it cannot generate true random.  I've had arguments with several people about this exact topic.  I, being a bit of a gambler, have a major problem with all of the games being "computerized" and allegedly pulling random numbers.  For instance, a modern slot machine allegedly uses the millisecond that a button is pushed to pull a reel stop point from a table.  The same theory applies to a lot of the modern gaming devices such as poker, blackjack, roulette, etc...  The problem with this, is that the numbers are not random at all, because they are based on a time stamp.  Just my take on the topic...

Comment: It's certainly possible to put bounds on the periodicity of the random number sequence.  Algorithms like Mersene Twister improve on LCG.  And there are things like diehard tests to quantify performance.  It's not as dire as you think.

Answer (score 0):

The computer does not know.

That's why when you ask for a "random" number, you get pseudo-random values.

This link (albeit it is wikipedia) gives a brief explanation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation#.22True.22_random_numbers_vs._pseudorandom_numbers

Answer (score 0):

A computer gains entropy from various things, such as the unix timestamp etc.
Therefore the 'random' numbers it generates are called pseudo-random.

Read: http://www.random.org/